# Minimal irrep of $ PSL(2,p) $

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, simple-groups

Below are some observations with a reference request. The question I really wanted to ask is whether the minimal irrep of $ PSL(2,p) $ can always be defined over $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}) $. In particular, for $ p $ congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $ is $ PSL(2,p) $ always a subgroup of $$
 SO\Big(\frac{p+1}{2},\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})\Big) 
$$
and for $ p $ congruent to $ 3 $ mod $ 4 $ is $ PSL(2,p) $ always a subgroup of
$$
 SU\Big(\frac{p-1}{2},\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})\Big) 
$$
where unitary matrices over $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}) $ have all their entries in $ \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{p}) $.

Certainly this holds for $ p=5 $ (the icosahedral subgroup of $ SO(3)  $) and for $ p=7 $ there's a $ PSL(2,7) $ subgroup of $ SU(3) $ but I'm not quite sure if it's defined over $ \sqrt{7} $ or something slightly bigger.

Observations with a reference request: (excellent reference now given in comments by David A. Craven)

For $ p < 40 $ I have noticed that the minimal degree $ d_{min} $ of a nontrivial irrep of $ PSL(2,p) $ is
$$
d_{min}=\frac{p+1}{2}
$$
if $ p $ is congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $ and is
$$
d_{min}=\frac{p-1}{2}
$$
if $ p $ is congruent to $ 3 $ mod $ 4 $.

I'm sure this fact must be well known in the literature. Does anyone have an explanation/proof/reference for this?

The value of the characters for degree $ d_{min} $ irreps are mostly $ 0,1,-1 $s also of course $ d_{min} $ and finally either
$$
\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}
$$
if $ p $ is congruent to $ 1 $ mod $ 4 $ or
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{-p}}{2}
$$
if $ p $ is congruent to $ 3 $ mod $ 4 $. There are always exactly two irreps of degree $ d_{min} $ and their characters are related exactly by  conjugation in the corresponding quadratic extension.

I assume all these patterns hold also for $ p > 40 $.

Comment: http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jda/characters/psl2/

Comment: OMG I took rep theory from Jeff Adams I should know this! He was a great teacher so sad that he's leaving our department :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes for both. For details see the answer by David E Speyer to the MO cross-post

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432148/minimal-irrep-of-mathrmpsl2-p

which in turn makes heavy use of the result

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432407/has-anyone-seen-this-construction-of-the-weil-representation-of-mathrmsp-2k

also from David E Speyer.

The key is using the Weyl representation for $ Sp_{2k}(\mathbb{F}_p) $ for the $ k=1 $ case since there is an exceptional isomorphism
$$
Sp(2,p)\cong SL(2,p)
$$
and so
$$
PSp(2,p)\cong PSL(2,p)
$$